# Examples of decreasing-in-some-time-interval variance of a time homogeneous Markovian process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, time-series

Let $x_t$ be a zero mean, time homogeneous Markovian process over time $t$ starting from $x_0=0$. What are the examples of $x_t$ where the variance at $t$ decrease over some interval of $t$? The following are my successful ( 1) ) and failed ( 2) ) attempts.

1) In discrete time and discrete state, the followig is a very simple example where the variance periodically oscillates over time.

$$x_{t+1} = \eta(1-|x_t|),\, x_0=0;\, \eta\in\{-1,1\},\mbox{ with probability of } \frac{1}{2} \mbox{ on each value of }\eta.$$

2) In continuous time, but discontinuous path setting. I first looked at the following jump diffusion process.

$$dx_t = -\alpha x_t dt+dz_t+ y\eta dN_t,\, x_0 = 0,$$
where $\alpha\gg 0$, $z_t$ is the standard brownian motion with mean $0$ and standard deviation $t$, $N_t$ is the Poisson process with frequency $0<\lambda\ll 1$, $\eta$ takes on values $-1$ or $1$ with $0.5$ probability each, $z_{t_1}$, $N_{t_2}$ and $\eta$ are independent of each other at arbitrary $t_1$ and $t_2$, and constant $y\gg 1$.

It does not seem a correct example. One can solve this equation and one will find the variance of this process is the sum of the variance from $dz_t$ and that from $dN_t$ due their independence. We may have to make the jumps negatively correlated to $z_t$.

Another setup I thought of is to shift $x_t$ beyond a barrier directly back to the $x=0$ line. So the process resides on the topology of two cylinders touched along a longitude. However, it seems to me, even this set up with $x_t$ being either a standard Browniam motion or mean reverting one still has its variance increasing over time.

Therefore, I am still without a valid example in this setup.

3) What are the examples for continuous path? I mainly want to look at process valued in $1$ dimension as it forces the path to revisit the same place when it goes away and then comes back closer to the origin. I suspect it is not possible. Can anyone prove this if it is indeed impossible?

Comment: What about the process given by $x_t = 0$, for $t\ge 0$?

Comment: @BenDerrett: Point accepted. Edited the question to decreasing-in-some-time-interval. Check it out.

Comment: @saz: Does time finiteness make a difference? You can not impose condition at the maximal time end, right?

Comment: @Hansen That's not what I meant, but unfortunately my idea doesn't work out either.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/q/151449/32660.